# Difference between depth and depth_registered?

Tags: ros, freenect, freenect-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you launch the freenect node there are topics with camera/depth/(SOMETHING) and camera/depth_registered/(SOMETHING). What is the difference between these two things?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264378/difference-between-depth-and-depth_registered?/) by [OwnageManFromLOL](https://answers.ros.org/users/30394/ownagemanfromlol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2017-06-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short:

`depth_registered` a cloud where each point is coloured (with the colour taken from the 2D image).

`depth` is a point cloud with no colour info.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OwnageManFromLOL](https://answers.ros.org/users/30394/ownagemanfromlol/) on 2017-06-23**:
Thanks for you answer!